# Apache - Can no longer use mod_rewrite after adding virtual directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

My apache server is set up with a very basic configuration. I used to serve just one website from apache, let's call it example.com.  Within the httpd.conf file, I had some code to force the website to always show www in the url.

I recently added a subdomain for the site, blog.example.com.  In order to do this I needed to create 2 virtual directory directives within my httpd.conf file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName blog.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
</VirtualHost>
```

Immediately after this, I kept my rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

The problem is that this after adding the Virtual Directory code, the rewrite code is no longer working.  I tried creating the following Directory directive, which doesn't seem to work at all.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from all
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Additionally, I tried creating a .htaccess file in the html folder of the website and restarting apache, but nothing that I put in there is getting noticed at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is all of this in the httpd.conf file, like one right after another, or in separate files?

Comment: This is all in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I just needed to move the rewrite logic within the start and end Directives.

Thanks for the help @animuson.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer from comment by original poster:**

> Ok, I figured it out. I just needed to move the rewrite logic within the start and end Directives. Thanks for the help @animuson. – Henry Wrinkler